# Get battery informations from android device

Tags: android, batterymanager

I try to get some informations about the android device battery like actual current, voltage,...
I succeed to get voltage, level, ... but unfortunately I have a phone which run with API 16 and the parameter BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW doesn't exist with this API because it appears with API 21.

So, how to get the current information and battery capacity info for example for this device ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for code?

Answer (score 3):

As the BatteryManager works with API 16. The following utils is useful.

```
package com.example.utils;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;

import com.example.app.AppContext;
import com.example.app.AppManager;

public class BatteryUtils {

    public static Intent getBatteryIntent() {
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        return AppContext.getInstance().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
    }

    public static int getScale(Intent intent) {
        return intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    }

    public static int getLevel(Intent intent) {
        return intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    }

    public static int getChargeStatus(Intent intent) {
        return intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    }

    public static boolean isCharging(int status) {
        return status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
    }

    public static boolean isCharging(Intent intent) {
        int status = getChargeStatus(intent);
        return isCharging(status);
    }

    public static void test() {
        Intent intent = BatteryUtils.getBatteryIntent();
        DebugUtils.log("isCharging:" + BatteryUtils.isCharging(intent) + ";level:" + BatteryUtils.getLevel(intent) + ";Scale:" + BatteryUtils.getScale(intent));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using BatteryManager. It works with API 16.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html

With it you can get the status(charging, full, discharging), capacity, if it is charging with USB or wirelessly, battery health and more